# How can I get a PHP JSON-encoded object as a variable on Javascript/JQuery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

So I am using PHP for server-side scripting, the php receives a string as a HTTP GET request and at the end, it echoes a JSON object.

How can I use Javascript/JQuery to get this JSON echo as a 'var' on javascript? I want to use this JSON object for client-side scripting.

```
$query = trim(strtolower($_GET["query"]), "?");
$stopList = array("much", "many", "the", "who", "what", "where", "when", "why", "how", "a", "is", "which", "so", "were", "there", "this", "did", "was", "will", "are", "you", "do", "I", "it", "are", "can", "i", "he", "she", "you", "did");
$templateFile = fopen("templates.txt", "r");
$templateList = array();
while(!feof($templateFile)) {
    array_push($templateList, fgets($templateFile));
}
fclose($templateFile);
$index = rand(0, count($templateList) - 1);
$template = $templateList[$index];
function makeTemplate($template, $subject, $stopList) {
    $listWords = explode(" ", $subject);
    $goodList = array_diff($listWords, $stopList);
    $answer = implode(" ", $goodList);
    $response = str_replace('#word', $answer, $template);
    return $response;

}
function containsUnwantedSymbol($haystack) {
    return substr($haystack, 0 , 1) === "#" || substr($haystack, 0, 1) === "@" || substr($haystack, 0, 4) === "http" || substr($haystack, 0, 5) === "https";;
}
require_once("TwitterAPIExchange.php");
$settings = array(
    "oauth_access_token" => "OAUTH_ACCESS_TOKEN_HERE",
    "oauth_access_token_secret" => "OAUTH_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET_HERE",
    "consumer_key" => "CONSUMER_KEY_HERE",
    "consumer_secret" => "CONSUMER_SECRET_HERE"
);
$url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json";
$requestMethod = "GET";
$getField = "?q=".$query;
$twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);
$response = $twitter->setGetfield($getField)
                        ->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
            ->performRequest();
$details = json_decode($response, true);
$tweet = $details['statuses'][0]['text'];
$list = explode(" ", $tweet);
$against = array();
for($item = 0; $item < count($list); $item++) {
    if($list[$item] == "RT") {
        unset($list[$item]);
    }
}
for($item = 0; $item < count($list); $item++) {
    if(containsUnwantedSymbol($list[item]) || containsUnwantedSymbol($list[$item]) || containsUnwantedSymbol($list[$item])) {
        unset($list[$item]);
    }
}
$tweet = implode(" ", $list);
$dreet = makeTemplate($template, $query, $stopList);
$clauses = array("durhamResponse" => $dreet, "twitterResponse" => $tweet);
shuffle($clauses);
$json_clauses = json_encode($clauses);

echo $json_clauses;
```

Notice at the bottom, I have echoed the JSON object that I would like to use in Javascript. How can I get this object from php as a var to use in Javascript?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#question').on('submit', function() {
        event.preventDefault();
        $.get("durhamServer.php", function() {
            $('#response1').load("durhamServer.php", $('#request').serialize());
        });
    });
});
```

This Javascript code displays the value of the php echo to the HTML page. How can I get this value as a var on javascript as I want to manipulate is client-side directly

Comment: The JSON encoded data will be passed back from the AJAX call function. Please show us the JS/ jQuery code you have that makes the AJAX call so we can provide you a better answer as to turn the data handed by PHP back into a variable in JS.

Comment: How do you call the php script? With ajax or directly? You can do it easily both way with [jquery .ajax method](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: Added the javascript which displays the echoed PHP value to the HTML page. How can I get that value as a var?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET", 
    url: url,
    success: function(response) {
        var variables = response;
    }
});
```

Comment: I'm assuming that var variables is the javascript var which stores the php result?

Answer (score 0):

First, you will use JQuery's Ajax to GET your PHP URL

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

```
$.ajax({
  method: "GET",
  url: <your php url>,
  success : <a function to handle the success>,
  error : <a function to handle any errors>
})
```

Your "echoed" php content will be handled by the `success` function (or `error`, if there is any error, like `404`, `500`, etc)

So your `success` function is the one that should do something with the data coming from the server. From the JQuery docs, here is how JQ arranges the data comming from the server:

```
Function( Anything data, String textStatus, jqXHR jqXHR )
```

So your echoed php data is contained on the first parameter, `data`

```
success : function(myPhpData, textStatus, jqXHR){
    // your echoed php data is now on myPhpData and you can do whatever you want with it
}
```

Remember that the Ajax call is asynchronous: the `success` function will execute only after the server responds. If you write anything after the ajax call, you can run a risk of a race condition -- so learn how to control the flow of your JavaScript code.